# Find the positive constants

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find positive constants, c0 and c1 such that, for all positive integers n,
$c_{0}n^{3} < 27n^{3} + 13n^{2} + 873(lg n)^{3} < c_{1}n^{3}$. Justify briefly.

I don't even know where to start.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could take $c_0=1$, and to find $c_1$ you could use $n^2\le n^3$ and $\ln n < n$ for every positive integer n.

Answer (score 0):

Since $0 < n^2 \le n^3$ and $0 \le \ln n < n$ when $n$ is a positive integer, you can set $c_0 = 27*1+13*0+873*0$ and $c_1 = 27*1+13*1+873*1$.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but where is that 1 coming from in $c_{0}$?

Comment: Because $1*n^3 \le n^3 \le 1*n^3$